# Sometimes i get "[error] There was an unexpected Alert! [Error processing request!]" in SeleniumIDE while running my tests

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-ide

I am facing quite a pickle with my seleniumTests. Sometimes I am getting `[error] There was an unexpected Alert! [Error processing request!]` while my test is still running. Nothing is visible in NW console, logs and basically, i cannot find more information why is this happening and how can I solve this.

I have already found some topics, where other guys were suggesting it could be caused when webapp is throwing unexpected alert and selenium don't know how to handle it.

Does anybody had the same problem and solved it successfully? I think every little hint how to fix this could push me to the final solution, so let's discuss it as much as possible.

Comment: How often is sometimes? 50% of the time? If you can enable your tests to take screenshots on failure, you'd be able to see what alert popped up. This might happen if your test tries to fill out of form but misses a field because something dynamic on the page cleared it out, and then clicking submit causes a popup alert, or a variety of other reasons depending on the application.

Comment: I would say it happens about 30% of the time..i also noticed, that it is not happening when the TC is small and runs only about a little amount of time, but when its larger and it runs about 5-10 minutes, iam getting this error quite often.
I also wrote waitForVisible + VerifyVisible on this element and they are OK everytime, even when the "click" command is failing, these two are OK, which seems strange to me.